# NodeJS Streams Waiting for all data to be streamed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream

My code is streaming data from a mongo collection and inserting it to another DB after doing some amount of operations on it.

I cannot seem to find a way to wait for the entire data to be operated on before closing the DB connections. The data is finished being worked on a few seconds after the stream is 'closed'. I want to wait for ALL the data 
 operations to be finished before closing the DB connections. How do i do that?

PS : I do see that all the data has been operated on. This works well. But I want to close the DB connections. I need to wait for all ops to finish before doing this!

```
var count = 0; // Counter for number of mongo docs that has been inserted in new_db
mongo_db.collection(config.collection, function (err, coll) {

    coll.find(config.mongo_query).count(function (e, coll_docs_count) {

        var stream = coll.find(config.mongo_query).stream();
        stream.on('close', function () {

            if (count === coll_docs_count) {
                // This NEVER executes since the data is finished
                //being operated and inserted in the NEW DB a few seconds after
                //this moment.
                mongo_client.close();
                cb_bucket.disconnect();
            }

        });

        stream.on('data', function (doc) {
            ... // Do some operations on it
            new_db.insert(doc, function (blah blah) {
                count++;
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: There's plenty of ways and it's very widely discussed, so you could probably look a bit harder. You need to be a lot more specific about what you want to do for each data event because you have an async call in there you also need to await and it looks like you really want bulk writes anyway. What version of NodeJS are you using? Please don't say less then 4 because if you are then you should upgrade before you run into a real problem and cannot reach out for official support.

Comment: Neil,
Using nodejs version 8 or 9, so that's fine.
I am inserting that data into a couchbase bucket. Couchbase nodejs sdks don't support bulk writes. 
I will look into using await - if that's what you suggest.